# Update SQL n:n table with multiple associations

Tags: postgresql

I have done this before, but before I mindlessly repeat something that I consider as a hack, I'm asking here.

I have 3 tables (details left out for clarity) :

#### inv_items

```
id bigserial (PK)
sku character varying(24)
name character varying(32)
...
```

#### inv_item_groups

```
id bigserial (PK)
name cahracter varying(32)
...
```

#### inv_item_group_members

```
item_group_id bigint (FK -> inv_item_groups)
item_id bigint (FK -> inv_items)
```

Now, in my code, I have an object like so (in pseudo-code)

```
class ItemGroup
   id:long
   groupName:String
   items:long[]
```

and these objects can be modified, then needs to be updated. Since I want to preserve the key integrity, I need the `inv_item_group_members` table (otherwise, I would've used [other solutions](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys/)).

Now, the usual way I was doing this was to

```
DELETE FROM inv_item_group_members WHERE item_group_id = $1
-- where $1 is the object's id
```

the, for each `items` in the object

```
INSERT INTO inv_item_group_members (item_group_id, item_id) VALUES ($1, $2)
```

Is there a better solution? What are the alternative? I'm thinking of a SQL function, but not really sure what's the best approach here (I'm not very experienced with PGSQL, yet.) I have read about [writable CTE](https://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/upsertmerge-using-writable-cte-in-postgresql-9-1/), but it does not address the case when elements are removed from the array (i.e. association removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [a working implementation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/upsert/) of an "UPSERT" command. So far, it works fine.

```
WITH upsert AS (UPDATE inv_items_group_members
                   SET priority = $3
                 WHERE group_id = $1
                   AND item_id = $2
             RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO inv_items_group_members 
            (group_id, item_id, priority) 
     SELECT $1, $2, $3 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you only delete from `inv_item_group_members` the items you deleted from the object and only insert into it the new items you added to the object.

You can do that by creating an `itemsToDelete` array, which you populate with item_ids each time you call the `removeItem` method of the class and an `itemsToInsert` which you populate each time you add an item whith the `addItem` method.

Then when you call the `save` method you delete the items whose item_id are present in the `itemsToDelete` array (obviously restricted also to group_id). Then you proceed to insert items present in the `itemsToInsert` array.

To make it resilient, you can either use a Map instead of arrays in order to prevent duplicates, or catch and ignore PK exceptions during the insert.

Comment: Right. I might try that. My model already has a `_previousData`, which is the original data, fetched from the database. I'm just worried that it's not as safe as I'd like it to be (i.e. race conditions), but I'll try that.